# How can I use fstream to get certain lines from a text file in c++

Tags: c++, text, fstream

I am working on a program where I need to get certain lines of text from a text file i.e. line 1 to line 4 then later on get line 5 to line 7. So I was wondering what I would need to do to do this using fstream

```
  std::ifstream infile("intro.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline (infile, line))
{
    std::cout <<line;
}
```

I did this but it outputs the entire document

Comment: And what have you tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to refine the condition reading the file to track how many lines were read so far. This can easily be done with a counter which is checked in combination with checking that a line could successfully be read (I could type the code but this would spoil the assignment).

Comment: so I need to add a counter that counts line 1,2,3,4 then stopsand then later counts line 5,6,7? Just making sure I understand

Comment: @user2998425: yes, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).